# copy row if ID blank with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I want to make the data in data base below

```
ID   Name   Card No 
1    A      3
            2 
2    B      1 
3    C      1
            2
```

to be like

```
ID   Name   Card No  
1    A      3 
1    A      2  
2    B      1  
3    C      1 
3    C      2
```

Using excel macros.. please help thanks :D

Update, my data is like this and the debugger only copy A & B column

```
Col->A    B      C         D
Row
7    ID   Name   Address   Card No 
8    1    A                3
9                          2 
10   2    B      X road    1 
11   3    C      Y road    1
12                         2
```

How to fix this? please help :( and it started in row 7

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple but below code will do the work:

**Note: Below code assumes your "Column C" do not have any empty cells. If you do please add comment so I can update.**

```
Sub copyPaste()
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<- Column that there is no empty cells

For i = 1 To lastRow
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
        Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**UPDATE: Below code will do the same job for all columns in the workbook. Code assumes that in the first row of worksheet you have headers and it is using this information to calculate how many iterations to do for columns.**

```
Sub copyPaste()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<- Column that there is no empty cells
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For j = 1 To lastCol
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
                Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Offset(-1, 0).Value
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah it's working thanks man!! But can I iterate A&B because my column length is up to "BD"

Comment: Hi, glad that worked. To do that there are 2 ways. 1 you can add IF function for each row (Which is not prefered) 2. We can add another for loop to go through all columns. I can help you about the second one. However I need to know if there is any column which will never have empty cell so we can use it as repeat reference. Of course I need to know which column is that.

Comment: and another question is. what would you like to do if the first row is empty. At that point you can not copy value from above right?

Comment: Yes, it cannot because my data is like this, i'll show you

Comment: what are you planning to do with row 8 column c? because there is no data to copy from above...

Comment: Hi Dubison, I am already done it thanks.. I'm using your update code btw :D thanks for your support